# making d3 force layout work with labeled data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, force-layout

I've been trying to glue ideas from various d3 examples into what i need, starting with the [basic example using `miserable.json` data](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) and then adding:

1. use of a key function for the data joins
2. modifying the underlying graph [ala this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795)
3. making the links' `linkDistance()` function depend on an attribute of the graph's links'
4. adding labels to the nodes [ala this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642)

So far i'm only 3 out of 4:  something about using the `g` elements -- using code taken directly from [the Mike's "Labeled Force Layout" example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642) -- breaks things and the nodes aren't drawn. I can make it work if i join `circle` elements directly, but not if I interpose `g` elements with attached circles and text elements.

The code below is my best effort at a minimal example. This example works, but does not if I replace the `.enter().append("circle")` line with the `.enter().append("g")` lines.

Does anyone know why?

```
var Width = 200;
var Height = 200;
var Pix2Len = 10;
var color = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", Width)
.attr("height", Height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
.size([Width, Height])

var graph = {
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","idx":0},
    {"name":"Napoleon","idx":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","idx":2},
    {"name":"Mme.Magloire","idx":3}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"len":1,"idx":"1-0"},
    {"source":2,"target":1,"len":4,"idx":"2-1"},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"len":8,"idx":"2-0"},
    {"source":3,"target":0,"len":10,"idx":"3-0"},
    {"source":3,"target":1,"len":4,"idx":"3-1"},
    {"source":3,"target":2,"len":6,"idx":"3-2"}
  ]
}

console.log("data loaded. nnode="+graph.nodes.length+" nlinks="+graph.links.length);

force
.nodes(graph.nodes)
.links(graph.links)
.size([Width, Height])
.linkDistance(function(link) {
    // console.log("link: "+link.source.name+' '+link.target.name+' '+link.idx+' '+link.len)
    return link.len * Pix2Len})
    .on("tick", tick);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(graph.links, function(d)  {return d.idx; })
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes, function(d) {return d.idx; })

// THIS WORKS
.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 8).style("fill", function(d) { return color(0); });

// BUT THIS DOES NOT
// modeled after http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642
//
//.enter().append("g")
//.attr("class", "node")
//.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
//.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
//
//node.append("circle")
//.attr("r", 10)
//.style("fill", function(d) { return color(0); });
//
//node.append("text")
//.attr("dx", 12)
//.attr("dy", ".35em")
//.text(function(d) { return d.name });

// 1. Begin with graph from JSON data
setTimeout(function() {
    start();
}, 0);

// 2. Change graph topology
setTimeout(function() {
    var new4 = {"name":"CountessdeLo","idx":4}
    var new5 = {"name":"Geborand","idx":5}
    graph.nodes.push(new4,new5);
    var link40 = {"source":4,"target":0,"len":1,"idx":"4-0"};
    var link43 = {"source":4,"target":3,"len":4,"idx":"4-3"};
    var link50 = {"source":5,"target":0,"len":1,"idx":"5-0"};
    var link52 = {"source":5,"target":2,"len":4,"idx":"5-2"};
    graph.links.push(link40,link43,link50,link52);

    start();
}, 3000);

//3. Change some link lengths

setTimeout(function() {

    // force.links().forEach(function(link) {
    graph.links.forEach(function(link) {
        if (link.idx == '1-0') 
            {link.len=10; }
        else if (link.idx == '3-0') 
            {link.len=2; }
        else if (link.idx == '5-0') 
            {link.len=10; };
    }); // eo-forEach
    start();
}, 6000);

function start() {
    link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.idx; });
    link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
    link.exit().remove();

    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.idx;});
    node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", function(d) {
    // tried with the <g> version above
//  node.enter().append("g").attr("class", function(d) {
        console.log('start:'+' '+d.name);
        return d.idx; }).attr("r", 5).style("fill", function(d) { return color(1); });
    node.exit().remove();

    force.start();
}

function tick() {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { 
        // console.log('tick:'+' '+d.name);
        return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}
//}  // eo-ready()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are setting `cx` and `cy` attributes to the `g` element. `g` elements does not support any position attributes like `x`, `y` or `cx`, `cy`. To move the contents of a `g` element you will have to use the `transform` attribute.

Your code

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
     .data(graph.nodes, function(d) {return d.idx; })
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; }) //will not work
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; }); //will not work
```

**Solution**

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
     .data(graph.nodes, function(d) {return d.idx; })
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "node");

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(0); });

node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

Use translate function as below to move group elements.

```
function tick() {
    //Moving <g> elements using transform attribute
    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zm11ow3t/1/)

Comment: thanks for your quick response @Gilsha; that seems to work.  i was updating `node.attr("cx")` in `tick()` following what i think of as [Mike's canonical force layout example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) and so i'm not sure why it works there and not here?  but it's working and i'll save that mystery for another day.

Comment: In that example, `node` is a collection of circles and here  `node` is a collection of group elements. That is why it works there.